# What's the best way to allow a user to save variables/options

Tags: forms

I have a user who wanted to save some configuration options for his site. I had initially created a content type of *Options*, then created a node for that user so they could edit it, and didn't allow them to delete or create any other nodes of this content type. But it feels like this isn't what content creation was created for!

Am I missing a trick in allowing users to save options, or should I just create a custom form and save it to db?

Comment: This is what [configuration entities](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/entity-api/configuration-entity) are essentially for

Comment: There's also [Config Pages](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_pages) if you'd prefer the configuration to be content.

Comment: @sonfd – I think it would be worth to have this added as a proper answer with the module synopsis blockquoted. Because one of the biggest advantages of Config Pages is that you don't need to ignore config from configuration management to prevent it gets overwritten on Live when importing config again during a deployment for example (is this right?). The module even states: `You can choose how (where) user will access this config page, so it can have a proper path like "admin/config/mysettings" and not explain to customer that he needs to create "a special node" in node/add.` – Perfect match.

Comment: @leymannx - good point, I agree. Done.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, instead of content entities you can use config entities. But for only a few configuration options this is too much effort. In this case you can use the [Simple Configuration API](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/configuration-api/simple-configuration-api), either by creating your own form

https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/configuration-api/working-with-configuration-forms

or by adding form values to existing admin forms in a form alter hook.

See for example how the core dblog module adds an option to /admin/config/development/logging when it is enabled:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() for system_logging_settings().
 */
function dblog_form_system_logging_settings_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $row_limits = [100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000];
  $form['dblog_row_limit'] = [
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Database log messages to keep'),
    '#default_value' => \Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('dblog.settings')->get('row_limit'),
    '#options' => [0 => t('All')] + array_combine($row_limits, $row_limits),
    '#description' => t('The maximum number of messages to keep in the database log. Requires a <a href=":cron">cron maintenance task</a>.', [':cron' => Url::fromRoute('system.status')->toString()]),
  ];

  $form['#submit'][] = 'dblog_logging_settings_submit';
}

/**
 * Form submission handler for system_logging_settings().
 *
 * @see dblog_form_system_logging_settings_alter()
 */
function dblog_logging_settings_submit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  \Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('dblog.settings')->set('row_limit', $form_state->getValue('dblog_row_limit'))->save();
}
```

Comment: +1 Maybe worth mentioning that the config then needs to be excluded from import/export somehow to prevent it gets overwritten on every configuration import. Maybe recommend [Config Ignore](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_ignore) or some other approach.

Comment: @leymannx, I don't think the OP has this requirement. Storing the config values in content was more an unwanted side effect caused by using a content type to generate the form.

Comment: I read it differently. At least it's a difference that maybe should be mentioned?

Answer (score 2):

In some cases it may be preferable for your configuration to actually be stored as content, you may not want it managed as part of the configuration system and/or it may be easier to work with if it's content. In those cases, the [Config Pages](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_pages) module is great.

From the module's *Do I need it* section:

> At some point I was tired of creating custom pages using menu and form API, writing tons of code just to have a page with an ugly form where a client can enter some settings, and as soon as a client wants to add some interactions to the page (drag&drop, ajax etc) things starts to get hairy. The same story was with the creation of dedicated CT just to theme a single page (like homepage) and explaining why you can only have 1 node of this type, or force it programmatically.

Some of these things aren't an issue in D8+ like they were in D7 and below, but the Config Form system still isn't 1:1 with Content Entity Forms.

**Some of the main features are:**

> Create fieldable entity using BO. FieldAPI, Features, views and other entity related modules are supported.

This gives you the ability to add fields and manage your form exactly the same way you would a node's form. It has a *Manage Fields* UI as well as a *Form Display* UI where you can build and manage your form without custom code.

> Mount your config page into menu structure as you like
> You can choose how (where) user will access this config page, so it can have a proper path like "admin/config/mysettings" and not explain to customer that he needs to create "a special node" in node/add.

The ability to place your form into the menu wherever you want and keep it out of the Content (nodes) area of your site. As you'd expect, the module provides its own permissions allowing you to give users the ability to edit or manage some or all of the *config_page* entities on the site.

> You no longer need to create a new content type that will store fields for your singleton pages like homepage and explain to a client that this page is content but can't create 2 nodes in it.

No need to worry about a second version of the page getting added and messing things up. That's all taken care of.

> Config pages are themable as any other entity, so with proper view mode configuration you can just drop CCT provided by this module on the Page (in Panel module) and have your config page rendered.

This is a really great feature - you can reference and render *config_page* entities just like any other content entity. This can be useful when you need to create a configuration form and then render some of that information in different places (e.g. some basic site information may need to render in header and footer). You can create and render view modes or programmatically render fields (using the config set in the UI). I find this to be significantly easier than trying to manually build a render array to render a value from my custom config form.

---

If you really want your configuration to act as configuration, i.e. live within the [configuration management system](https://www.drupal.org/docs/configuration-management) and get pushed around environments via code, then a normal config entity/form is the right option. However, if you don't want or care about that, the Config Pages module is a great alternative and allows you to manage your config form and displays easily via the UI, the same way you'd manage a node's form and displays.